# Django Prefetching Nested FKs not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, prefetch

I have been working on this for a bit but I cannot seem to get prefetching to work correctly in my instance. I am trying to run a nested `Prefetch()` to prefetch items from a prefetched object, but the attribute is not being stored as usual. Can somebody please show me what I am doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
primary_residents = Resident.objects.filter(
        property=request.session['property'], type='primary', user__is_active=True
    ).select_related(
        'unit', 'unit__building', 'user'
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('current_balance',
                 queryset=Balance.objects.filter(is_active=True).prefetch_related(
                     Prefetch('charges',
                              queryset=Charges.objects.filter(date_entered__range=(
                                      previous_month, property.close_out_start_date_plus_one()), reversed=False
                              ).prefetch_related(
                                  'code', 'balance'),
                              to_attr='previous_charges'
                              )
                 ), to_attr='active_balance'
                 ),
    )
for p in primary_residents:
    # errors out, previous_charges is not a valid attr
    print(p.active_balance.previous_charges)
```

Comment: `active_balance` will be a list. So to access `previous_charges`, you have to iterate through each active balances, so something like: `for a in p.active_balance: a.previous_charges`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution.

```
primary_residents = Resident.objects.filter(
        property=request.session['property'], type='primary', user__is_active=True
    ).select_related(
        'unit', 'unit__building', 'user'
    ).prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('current_balance',
                 queryset=Balance.objects.all().prefetch_related(
                     Prefetch('charges',
                              queryset=Charges.objects.filter(date_entered__range=(previous_month, property.close_out_start_date_plus_one()), has_been_reversed=False
                                                              ).prefetch_related('code', 'balance', 'charges_history'),
                              to_attr='previous_charges'
                              ),
                     Prefetch('payments',
                              queryset=Payments.objects.filter(date_entered__range=(previous_month, property.close_out_start_date_plus_one()), has_been_returned=False
                                                               ).prefetch_related('code', 'balance'),
                              to_attr='previous_payments'
                              ),
                     Prefetch('charges',
                              queryset=Charges.objects.filter(date_entered__range=(previous_month, property.close_out_start_date_plus_one()), has_been_reversed=False
                                                              ).prefetch_related('code', 'balance'),
                              to_attr='current_charges'
                              ),
                     Prefetch('payments',
                              queryset=Payments.objects.filter(date_entered__range=(previous_month, property.close_out_start_date_plus_one()), has_been_returned=False
                                                               ).prefetch_related('code', 'balance'),
                              to_attr='current_payments'
                              ),
                 )
                 )
    )
    for p in primary_residents:
            print(p.current_balance.previous_charges)
```